# How can I attach the jar produced by one maven module to another module with a classifier?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a project for which I've done some refactoring (and module names clarifications).

As a consequence, the module that was `neo4j-connector-impl` has now become `neo4j-connector-1.6`. Now, for better compatibility, i want to have the jar produced by this project also be available as `neo4j-connector-impl` (its old name, if you follow me).

I have created a `pom` typed project under those GAV coordinates, and have tried attaching the jar using a mix of [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Unfortunatly, each time I build my project, that jar is not in maven repository and maven says

```
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ndx\Documents\workspaces\git\neo4j-connector\neo4j-connector-impl-parent\neo4j-connector-impl\neo4j-connector-impl-1.6.jar to C:\Users\ndx\.m2\repository\com\netoprise\neo4j-connector-impl\1.6-SNAPSHOT\neo4j-connector-impl-1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] Skipped re-installing C:\Users\ndx\Documents\workspaces\git\neo4j-connector\neo4j-connector-impl-parent\neo4j-connector-impl\neo4j-connector-impl-1.6.jar to C:\Users\ndx\.m2\repository\com\netoprise\neo4j-connector-impl\1.6-SNAPSHOT\neo4j-connector-impl-1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar, seems unchanged
```

So ... how can I put that jar as a classified dependency ?

For info, here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.netoprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-connector-impl-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>neo4j-connector-impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>Compatibility module ensuring previous code can "quite" work</description>
    <properties>
        <dependencies.directory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</dependencies.directory>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}-1.6</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <outputDirectory>${dependencies.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- attach all projects artifact to this one in order for user projects 
                to have minimum integration work -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <!--  for maximum compatibility, the 1.6 version is attached as default jar artifact -->
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>neo4j-connector-impl-1.6.jar</file>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                            <basedir>${dependencies.directory}</basedir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT 1** Why are there versions numbers in artifacts ? Because that project (neo4j-jca-connector), provides access to neo4j graph database to various JavaEE servers. The neo4j version **SHOULD NOT** be constrained by this connector. As a consequence, we have to provide users a way to define, for a version of that connector, which neo4j version is used (considering as default - for backwards compatibility version - the 1.6 one).

As a consequence, we have one module for each version of neo4j,n and these modules are aggregated here. For the record, [Bouncycastle](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/bouncycastle/) do so for JDK versions ... in an even worse version, to my mind, as they use the JDK version directly in artifactId, what I plan to do only internaly : exposed artifacts will be neo4j-connector-impl and neo4j-connector-rar ... and classifiers will allow one to select which neo4j version to use.

**EDIT 2** For more info, the whole project can be seen on github : https://github.com/Riduidel/neo4j-connector

The parent pom cotnaining the maven-shade-plugin declaration is https://github.com/Riduidel/neo4j-connector/blob/master/neo4j-connector-impl-parent/pom.xml

One version of that connector is https://github.com/Riduidel/neo4j-connector/blob/master/neo4j-connector-impl-parent/neo4j-connector-impl-1.5/pom.xml

And expected aggregator module should be https://github.com/Riduidel/neo4j-connector/blob/master/neo4j-connector-impl-parent/neo4j-connector-impl/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is much clearer after reading your comment and EDIT.

So, correct me if I'm wrong.

- You want to be able to provide a version of your connector for each neo4j version
- You use module to do so.

What is still not clear to me, is that I cannot see the modules' part of your POM. You say that you want to use classifiers (so, of the same project) but maven modules are different projects...

Comment: The version number in the artifact **IS NOT** my project one, but is neo4j one ... a dependency which I have, indeed, but for which I want to maintain maximum compatibility. FTR, I think BouncyCastle also maintains compatibility with various JDK versions this way (or by using classifiers).